# How to call to an extension from another viewcontroller in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, extension-methods

I have an extension like this in one view controller.

```
extension UIViewController {
func hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround() {
    let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(UIViewController.dismissKeyboard))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

func dismissKeyboard() {
    view.endEditing(true)
}
}
```

Can I call this extention within another `ViewController`. If so how can I do it?
Please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

It's simple. In any other view controller you would just write

```
self.hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()
self.dismissKeyboard()
```

Any extension you have defined is instantly available to any instance of the class you have extended.

Comment: @Said How to use this extension for Objective C Viewcontrollers?

Comment: You'll need to add `@objc` prefix to your method.